# How do I send a control character down a socket in PHP?

Tags: php, control-characters, php-socket

In a PHP script I am writing, I need to send a control+z character down a network socket I have previously created. I understand the ctrl+z character to be chr(26), so at the end of the string I am sending I have added a new line (\r\n) and then the chr(26) as follows:

```
$socket=fsockopen($host['host'],$host['port']);
fputs($socket, "I am a message\r\n" . chr(26));
fclose($socket);
```

Sadly, this isn't sending a Ctrl+Z, as I'd hoped it would.

Regards,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably being sent just fine.  Add extra text after the ^Z to confirm.

The question is what do you want it to do when it gets there?  Does the program you're communicating with handle a ^Z character how you'd expect it to?

Comment: I'm actually using PHP to programatically send SMS messages using a mobile phone in PDU mode. If I use the Text Mode and telnet in to the device, then it does process the Ctrl+z, although now that I've tried that in PDU mode, it doesn't seem to have worked. I'll check out sending text mode with PHP.

Comment: I stopped using PDU mode, as it wasn't recognising the Ctrl+Z character. I moved to using Text mode, which did work most of the time. I then discovered a separate application called Gammu which provided the SMS interface I needed. Thanks for your help!